# using array_push($var); with keys

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

```
$dizi = array(
"tr" => "Turkey",
"uk" => "United Kingdom",
"us" => "United States"
);
```

i want to add `"br"=>"brasil"` to end of the array.

thanks.

Comment: Learn more about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A syntax construct that's a bit closer to [`array_push`](http://php.net/array_push) would be:

```
 $dizi += array("br" => "Brasil");
```

Note the **+=**
But for a single addition you should prefer the direct array assignment (as pointed out in the other answers).

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing to it:

```
$dizi['br'] = 'brasil';
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just do:

```
$dizi['br'] = "brasil"
```